# Pasting a column from column names of a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a list(list1) with n elements. Each element of list1 is data frame(`df1, df2, ..., dfn`) with different(also maybe same number) number of columns.

Let i'th element(data frame) dfi with column names `x1,x2,x3,....,xi`.

I want to paste such a formula with column names:

```
x1+x2+x3+......+xi.
```

And assign this formula as i'th element of a list(list2).

I want to this for each data frame in list1.

How can I do this using R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Ex: Let list1 have two elements(two data frames: df1 and df2)

```
list1[[1]]:

df1:

x1  x2  x3
--  --  --
43  12  7
3   6   5
```

and

```
list1[[2]]:

df2:

x1  x2 
--  -- 
21  45 
14  16
```

I want to return list2 which is:

```
list2[[1]]:

x1+x2+x3
```

and

```
list2[[2]]:

x1+x2
```

I am not interested with elements of data frames(df1 and df2), just with the column names.

Comment: Please illustrate the problem with example data and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, this may do the work for you?
`list2 <- lapply(list1, function(x) { return(paste(names(x), collapse = "+")) })`

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want:
    `list2 <- lapply(list1, function(x){apply(x, 1, sum)})`?

Comment: No @Ivan Vanchev. I am not interested with sum of columns. I am just interested with the column names. Psidom's suggestion does what I want. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do something similar recently. I dont have a gracious solution, but the below will work only if you have equal number of columns in all the dataframes.

```
length_list <- length(list1)
cols_in_df <- ncol(list[[i]])
i = 1
for(i in 1:length_list)
{
    assign(model[i], lm( list[[i]][1]+ list[[i]][2]+ ....+list[[i]][cols_in_df])
}
```